# Make categorical legend from continuous data

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have created this ggplot:

```
ggplot(incumb, aes(ObamaVote, VoteShare, color=ObamaCare)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_dark () + 
  xlab("Member's District Vote for Obama in 2008 (%)") + 
  ylab("Member's Vote Share in 2010 (%)") + 
  ggtitle("Member's District Vote for Obama in 2008 and Vote Share in 2010") +
  geom_smooth(method='lm')
```

Which produces this:

[image: Graph]

The variable of the legend represents whether a congressional member voter for (1) or against (0) ObamaCare. Thus, I want the legend to represent the binary and not four options. And I want the legend to "Voted Yes" for 1 and "Voted No" for 0.

Can this be done?

I have looked around on the internet and I have not even been able to attempt anything so far.

Comment: Ggplot is treating the ObamaCare column as a continuous numeric variable. Try converting the column to a factor.

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your input data before ggplot with the code below

```
incumb$ObamaCare <- factor(incumb$ObamaCare, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("Voted No","Voted Yes"))
```

I hope this helps!